# How to perform if...else statement in javascript ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have these code:

```
function ambil_coa(hal_aktif,scrolltop){
  if($('table#coa-list').length > 0){
    // alert('ada tablenya');
    $.ajax('http://'+host+path+'/ambil',{
      dataType:'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        $('table#coa-list tbody tr').remove();
        $.each(data.record , function(index, element){
           $('table#coa-list').find('tbody').append(
                '<tr align="center">'+
                ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+element.no_urut+'</td>'+
                ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+element.customer_ID+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'               
            )
        });
      }

    });
  }
}
```

I want to add some conditional statement below.

If `element.customer_ID` return `0`, `echo "-"`;
`else` if the value not 0 `echo "Customer Name"`

How to write the conditional script to the `append` section?

Comment: You can user html(' your html code ') or append()

Comment: var element = "";

$.each(data.record , function(index, element){
           element += '<tr align="center">'+
                ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+element.no_urut+'</td>'+
                ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+element.customer_ID+'</td>'+
                '</tr>';               
            )
        });

$('table#coa-list').html(element);

Comment: It is not clear what you are actually trying to ask here. Can yu be a bit more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way will be using ternary operator:

```
$('table#coa-list').find('tbody').append(
    '<tr align="center">'+
    ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+element.no_urut+'</td>'+
    ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+(element.customer_ID == 0? '-' : 'Customer Name' )+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'               
)
```

If you want to use another element property, then:

```
$('table#coa-list').find('tbody').append(
    '<tr align="center">'+
    ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+element.no_urut+'</td>'+
    ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+(element.customer_ID == 0? '-' : element.customer_Name )+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'               
)
```

Comment: It's return _Customer Name_ to each row, even if `element.customer_ID` not zero. Any idea?

Comment: If `Customer name` is shown then all customer_ID are not zeroes, you can check them with `console.log` for example.

Comment: my bad, yes you right. It's fully work. How to replace the `Customer name` with value of `element.customer_address`?

Comment: See second example please.